# Fourier Transform Sign Convention

Tags: calculus, fourier-transform

If I have three coupled equations

\begin{equation}\label{22}
\rho \ \xi_{,t} = \tau_{21,1} + \tau_{23,3},
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{23}
\tau_{21,t} = c_{66} \ \xi_{,1} + c_{46} \ \xi_{,3},
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{24}
\tau_{23,t} = c_{46} \ \xi_{,1} + c_{44} \ \xi_{,3}.
\end{equation}

and I want to solve them by using Fourier transforms defined as

\begin{equation}
\check \xi(\omega, \underline x) = \int \xi_2( t, x_1, x_3) \ e^{i\omega t} \ dt,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\check \tau_{21}(\omega, \underline x) = \int \tau_{21}( t, x_1, x_3) \ e^{i\omega t} \ dt,
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\check \tau_{23}(\omega, \underline x) = \int \tau_{23}( t,x_1, x_3) \ e^{i\omega t} \ dt .
\end{equation}

Can I change the sign convention in one of the Fourier transforms, for example, solving with

\begin{equation}
\check \xi(\omega, \underline x) = \int \xi_2( t, x_1, x_3) \ e^{i\omega t} \ dt,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\check \tau_{21}(\omega, \underline x) = \int \tau_{21}( t, x_1, x_3) \ e^{-i\omega t} \ dt,
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\check \tau_{23}(\omega, \underline x) = \int \tau_{23}( t,x_1, x_3) \ e^{i\omega t} \ dt .
\end{equation}

where $\tau_{21}$ has changed to a negative convention whilst the other two remain as positive convention? Is this permitted?

Comment: Wouldn't $\tilde{\xi}(t,\,\underline{k}):=\int\xi_2(t,\,x_1,\,x_3)e^{i(k_1x_1+k_3x_3)}d^2\underline{k}$ etc. be a more useful FT? It would reduce your PDEs to ODEs in $t$.

Comment: I do take a FT in space after I take in time. Do you know though if what I'm asking in the question is valid?

Comment: "I do take a FT in space after I take in time" Really? Please edit your question to show us how.

Comment: It's irrelevant to my question,  I don't need to show it!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the sign for $\omega$ in computing $\check \tau_{21}(\omega, \underline x)$, you have flipped the sign of the $\omega$ axis in the transform domain compared to your other transformations.  Unless $\tau_{21}(t, ...)$ is real and even with respect to the time axis, your result for $\check \tau_{21}(\omega, \underline x)$ will be inconsistent with the other $\check \tau_{nm}(\omega, \underline x)$ functions.